# How do I find PCI device using IPMI over the network

Tags: pci, ipmi

I've been having quite a time trying to use IPMI tools (such as OpenIPMI, FreeIPMI, and ipmitool) to discover and monitor a PCI device in my server.  Using an IBM server going through IMM over the network using the IPMI tools, I can't seem to be able to get any information on the PCI devices in the server.  The IPMI tools only return basic information on the system such as the BMC, chassis, power supplies, fans, etc.  No information on the devices plugged into the PCI slots.

I've tried basic commands like "fru list", "sdr elist", etc. and haven't been able to get any information from the PCI slots.

Just hoping someone has had experience using these tools and is able to get information from the devices in the PCI slots.

Specifically, I would like to get the FRU information as well as device ID, I2C slave address, etc. for accessing the device.

Thanks for any information that you can provide...

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement in the IPMI spec that the PCI connector A side pins 40 and 41 that contain the SMBus are routed to the BMC. A vendor may do it but most do not.

Look at it this way, the BMC can turn off power to the PCI bus and main CPUs. You would not be able to read anything from them anyway.

This is why the AdvancedTCA specification requires management power and two IPMB buses to each blade slot. The AdvancedTCA spec requires the IPMB bus from each slot is connected to the BMC. The blade can power up and use a max 15 watts to supply IPM Controller and you can read the data you are looking for without powering on the main CPUs.

Hank Bruning
JBlade

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Unfortunately, my server is an IBM rack mount server and not a ATCA based device.  But, given your answer, is there a way to tell the BMC to turn power on the PCI bus and get information through IPMI?

Thanks...

Comment: If there is a way, it is going to be an IBM OEM IPMI command or a method that is not part of IPMI.